# django query - show new players count grouped monthwise

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am trying to create a dashboard in django for a gaming site. I need to show a monthly "new players who joined game" graph. I am already getting total players, and players joined in current month and last 7 days using the following code:

```
queryset = Players.object.all()
current_year = datetime.now().year
current_month = datetime.now().month
one_week_ago = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=7)
count['players_all'] = queryset.count
count['players_current_month'] = queryset.filter(joined__month=current_month, created_at__year=current_year).count
count['players_last_seven_days'] = queryset.filter(joined__gte=last_seven_days).count
```

Now I want to add a new `dict` which will show me count of players who joined last 12 months, grouped by month. Something like:

```
count['players_last_twelve_months'] = get_players_last_twelve_months()
```

Then I want to define this function `get_players_last_twelve_months()` such that it will return something like:

```
     {
        Jul:12
        Aug:15
        Sept:9
        Oct:22
        Nov:11
        Dec:7
        Jan:14
        Feb:19
        Mar:20
        Apr:12
        May:25
        Jun:8
       }
```

I am very new to python and django. Using my minimal knowledge I know I can use variations of the `queryset.filter` I used above like.

```
queryset.filter(joined__month=11, current_year = 2017)
queryset.filter(joined__month=12, current_year = 2017)
queryset.filter(joined__month=1, current_year = 2018)
queryset.filter(joined__month=2, current_year = 2018)
```

However I dont want to hardcode month numbers etc. Can anyone provide me some pointers on the proper way to try to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter, extract year and month and annotate. 
Something like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear, ExtractMonth
from django.db.models import Count

year_ago = datetime.date(...) # compute date year ago 

queryset.filter(joined__gte=year_ago).annotate(
    year=ExtractYear('joined'), month=ExtractMonth('joined')
).values('year','month').order_by('year','month').annotate(c=Count('id'))
```

Comment: it said `TypeError: values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'year'`